# Incapaz de eliminar símbolo de interrogación de texto obtenido con Jsoup

Tags: java

El texto que quiero obtener usando Jsoup es el siguiente (la web [esta](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/store/p/astroneer-game-preview/9nblggh43kzb)):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo obtengo bien, sin embargo me aparecen 2 símbolos de interrogación al mostrarse en mi web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He acudido al HTML de la web original y me he fijado que aparece un símbolo `&nbsp;`, con lo que he pensado que a la hora de guardar la información de la descripción en la variable de Java, lo reemplace por un espacio normal, de esta forma:

```
String descripcion_castellano = doc.select(".c-content-toggle .m-product-detail-description").text().replace("&nbsp;"," ");
```

Pero aunque en la base de datos aparece un espacio, me sigue mostrando los símbolos de interrogación.

Comment: Si pintas por consola el valor de `doc.select(".c-content-toggle .m-product-detail-description").text()` te pinta el `&nbsp;` en la consola?

Comment: @Hictus No, me aparece un espacio normal. Igual que lo que se guarda en la base de datos.